# What is .arm in assembly code ?

Tags: assembly, arm

The following code is taken from https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/blob/master/arch/arm/kernel/head.S

I have never done ARM assembly programming so can some help me understand what exactly is going on in these lines? what is .ar.? etc:

```
.arm           
    __HEAD
ENTRY(stext)

 THUMB( adr     r9, BSYM(1f)    )   @ Kernel is always entered in ARM.
 THUMB( bx  r9              )   @ If this is a Thumb-2 kernel,
 THUMB( .thumb                  )   @ switch to Thumb now.
 THUMB(1:                       )
```

Also kindly point me some tutorials to getting starting with.

Comment: The ARM specific features of **gas**, the gnu assembler are [all documented](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM_002dDependent.html).  In assembler, anything like `.directive`, is a directive or command to the assembler to change some behavior.  There are [generic directives](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Pseudo-Ops.html) and [arm specific directives](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html).  Try [DaveSpace](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/) and the [ARM GCC cookbook](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html) for more.

Answer (score 6):

Plenty of ARM microcontrollers have two different instruction sets:

1. The default 32 bit ARM instruction set
2. The lightweight 16 bit Thumb instruction set

During a program execution, the ARM chip can switch between two modes in order to run instructions from any of these sets.

> The purpose of these lines seems to be the selection of the right mode
>   (i.e., .arm or .thumb) in order to execute properly the subsequent
>   code.

EDIT: Sorry, I made a mistake. The real purpose is to specify which set of instruction will be used in the generated code. For example, if you write `add r0, r1, #3`, the binary instruction produced belong either to the ARM or the Thumb instruction set, depending on which directive you chose between `.arm` and `.thumb`.

From https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html :

> .arm
>
> This performs the same action as .code 32.

-

> .thumb
>
> This performs the same action as .code 16.

-

> .code [16|32]
>
> This directive selects the instruction set being generated.
>   The value 16 selects Thumb, with the value 32 selecting ARM.

Answer (score 1):

The assembler directives `.arm` (alias for `.code 32`) and `.thumb` (alias for `.code 16`) are used to switch between standard ARM instruction encoding and Thumb instruction encoding.

See also: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/as/ARM-Directives.html